# Struts 2 Access messages with JSTL instead of s:text

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl

In struts 2 the

```
<s:property value="#pageTitle" />
```

(is equivalent to...)

```
JSTL: ${pageTitle}
```

I use JSTL version which is more compact.

Can we do the same thing with application messages?! To get text from message resources we do as below:

```
<s:text name="label.sample" />
```

Now, is there any JSTL version insteadof `<s:text/>` ?

---

Meanwhile, I tried to find a way to pass textprovider to jsp. But I could not find a way

```
public class BaseActionSupport extends ActionSupport{

  //Same as ActionSupport
  private TextProvider Provider; //with setter and getter

  public TextProvider getSampleTextProvider() {

            TextProviderFactory tpf = new TextProviderFactory();
            if (container != null) {
                container.inject(tpf);
            }
            return  tpf.createInstance(getClass(), this);
  }

}
```

In jsp:

```
${provider.text("label.password")} //Error The function text must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

Is it a correct approach?!

PS: In the http://notsoyellowstickies.blogspot.com/2011/05/making-struts-2-and-jstl-share-message.html mentioned that I can somehow share struts 2 and jstl messages, but I should still use `<fmt:message key="sample.label"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action object is exposed and one can use its methods:

```
${action.getText('sample')}
```

This is JSTL method invocation and you need JSTL 2.2 (ex: tomcat 7)

Please refer to:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/struts-user/201405.mbox/%3CCAMopvkNtiTDB0MV97s-tD4JhhZnfJ2bOMcZXu3NJOvyDu9SVaA@mail.gmail.com%3E

(Your action must extend ActionSupport, to use above)